# SQLITE manager on a server

Tags: java, database, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I was wondering if it was possible to get an SQLITE manager database onto a server? What i mean by this is so that when i complete my program in a java project and make an installer for that project. Anyone who downloads it from any computer running on any operating system  who has administration rights can access the database without having connection issues. In addition anyone who logs in to the program can do so with full database connection.

Is there a way to do this? I also don't want the user who is going to install the program to install any additional programs for the database. In addition i would like this program to work on any computer who might not have the SQLITEManager plugin on there firefox web browser or even have firefox installed on there computer.

I would also like the admin to be able to edit anything on the online server the database should be on. 
If this is not possible on SQLITE Manager could you recommend a database which can do this but also use and work on the code already made for the sqlite programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite databases are just flat-files.  What this means in layman's terms:

- I download your database as a file.
- I can modify it as I please.
- I'm not forced to synchronize to the newer version of the flat-file.

You have a choice:  You either write your code to force periodic synchronization of the SQLite flat-file to your clients, or you use a dedicated DBMS on your server, such as [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), and force your clients to connect to that.

Comment: Any links on how to write `code to force periodic synchronization of the SQLite flat-file to your clients` ?

Comment: That has to do mostly with socket programming.  You should be able to find resources on the 'Net that relate to that alone.